# Confirm dialog in Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm writing an app in javascript and html with phonegap/cordova.
I have this code in javascript:

```
$('#diario_delete_btn').live('tap',function(e){
    var iddb = $(this).find('a').attr('rel');
    confirm_diario_delete(iddb);        
});

function diario_delete(iddb) {
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "123nozze", 200000); 
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM AgendaItemJDO WHERE id='+iddb); 
        lastChangeUpdate();
    });

    $('.diario_row[db_id="'+ iddb +'"]').remove();
    $('#popupMenuDiario').popup("close");
}

function confirm_diario_delete(iddb) {
    var r = confirm("Confermi l'eliminazione dell'elemento?");
    if (r) {
        diario_delete(iddb);
    } else {
        $('#popupMenuDiario').popup("close");
    } 
}
```

It seems to work but if I choose "cancel button" (so r = false) n times before I press "confirm button", next time the confirm dialog is displayed 2 times, next time it is displayed 3 times, and so on. I don't know why this behaves this way. The same is if a change the code and I use the Cordova example code for confirm dialog.

Any ideas on what is the problem and how can I solve it?
Thanks!

Comment: How do you press the cancel button n times before the confirm button? When I press cancel the dialog dismisses immediately and I don't have time to push it more than once. Are you somehow tapping the button at superhuman speeds? What device are you testing this on? Also, you should be using the notification plugin since Cordova/Phonegap uses confirm, prompt, etc., to pass messages from the javascript to the native code. (confirm, prompt, etc., might work but it's not safe.) Try it with http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.confirm

Comment: I'll try as soon as possible. However the confirm dialog appear, I choose the cancel button, it dismisses and then reappears.

Comment: It shouldn't reappear if you hit the cancel button. Can you try to just make a very simple confirm dialog and see if you can reproduce the behavior without jQuery? I'm thinking maybe something is goofy in your jquery code but it doesn't look wrong (I don't use jquery though...)

Answer (score 4):

You should use the native [notification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_notification_notification.md.html) which Phonegap supports.

Specifically the .confirm() method taken from link above;

```
// process the confirmation dialog result
function onConfirm(button) {
    alert('You selected button ' + button);
}

// Show a custom confirmation dialog    
//

navigator.notification.confirm(
    'You are the winner!',  // message
    onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
    'Game Over',            // title
    'Restart,Exit'          // buttonLabels
);
```

Comment: With this code I have the same problem and moreover it doesn't execute the onConfirm function.

Comment: It won't fire the confirm if no confirm is shown, so something is stopping the alert from showing. If you place a console log just before navigator.notification.confirm() does it output to the console?

Answer (score 2):

```
   navigator.notification.confirm(
        'Are you sure you want to signup ',  // message
        onConfirm,              // callback to invoke with index of button pressed
        'SignUp',            // title
         ['yes','no']             // buttonLabels
    );

    function onConfirm(buttonIndex){
    alert('You selected button ' + buttonIndex);
    if(buttonIndex==2){
    alert('You selected button - no');
    }else{
    alert('You selected button - yes');

    }

    }
```